# Python faulthandler: Output to both stderr and (log) file?

Tags: python, debugging, segmentation-fault

#### Background

We're developing a Pyside6 application where we have many segmentation faults and we have enabled Python's [faulthandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html) to help with debugging these segfaults

By default faulthandler will write to stderr, but we want to capture these problems in a file, so right now we are writing segfaults to our logfile. This is what our code looks like:

```
log_file_fd=open(log_path, "a")
faulthandler.enable(log_file_fd)
```

#### Problem

Since we are writing faulthandler/segfault info to a file, we no longer get this output in the console when running the application

#### Question

**Is it possible (and if so how) to send the output to both stderr and to a log file?**

(I understand that the `enable` function takes a single file descriptor as argument, but is there a workaround for achieving this goal?)

---

Environment:

- Python version: 3.10
- We'd like the solution to work on GNU/Linux, Windows and MacOS

---

I have social anxiety and have a need for kindness, so please try to be respectful when commenting or answering. Then i can learn from you without shame. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm more of a Unix programmer than a Python programmer I would first suggest trying to wrap your Python program in a shell script that would run `tee(1)` on the output from stderr, e.g.:

```
pyprog 2>&1 >/dev/tty | tee -a /path/to/stderr.logfile
```

Alternately you might be able to use `os.popen()`, or perhaps `subprocess.Popen()`, to open a sub-process running `tee` to achieve the same thing from within your Python code.

```
lfp = suprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/tee", "-a", log_path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=STDERR, stderr=STDERR, close_fds=True)
faulthandler.enable(lfp.stdin)
```

*This is so far entirely untested, just my best guess using examples from the documentationd.*

Also neither of these are likely to work on Windows, unless perhaps you have some POSIX-compatible environment available with a shell, `tee(1)`, `/dev/tty`, etc.  Sorry, I just don't ever do Windows.